# Kubenetes accsess api web

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Im new to Kub and i converted my envirement from docker-compose,
I have a pod that have python code  - if i use my docker on the same host i can accsess
but when its on pod no traffic goes inside,

## kubectl config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://10.10.10.130:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

api-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert --volumes hostPath
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
  name: api
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "5001"
    port: 5001
    targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: api
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

api-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert --volumes hostPath
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: api
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert --volumes hostPath
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 127.0.0.1:5000/api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: "Never"
        name: api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /base
          name: api-hostpath0
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /root/ansible/api/base
        name: api-hostpath0
status: {}
```

pod log:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'server' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://10.244.0.17:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 553-272-086
```

I tried reaching what the config view shows and i get this :
https://10.10.10.130:6443/

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

The path to reach through container is :
https://10.10.10.130:5001/
It does not reach container and says like site does not exists -
again this works on docker container so what am i missing ?

Thanks

**--EDIT--**

If i curl http://10.244.0.17:5001/ (the address the api pod) from host i get in, why i cannot get in from outside?

Also tried adding nginx + api pod deployment

```
  template:
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
```

Still cannot reach please help

Comment: what happen if you use kubectl port-forward api 5001:5001 after that got to your browser and check localhost:5001 and give me the response

Comment: @rassakra  Didnt have any effect `kubectl port-forward api-5cb96dd789-ftlwd 5001:5001
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5001 -> 5001
Forwarding from [::1]:5001 -> 5001`

Comment: yes now you application is accessoble from localhost:5001

Comment: But it doesn't work - i get `This site can’t be reached` on hostip 10.10.10.130:5001 or 127.0.0.1:5001 , i need it to work on host ip i dont understand , with docker it works what am i missing?? @rassakra

Comment: You need to specify the NodePort type to your service. This way it will expose on all the hosts of the kubernetes cluster at a port, usually in the range of 30k-32k or something like that

Comment: @AndD I did try to add NodePort  in service type but it didnt work, i ended up adding the externalIPs  and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!
I needed to add  `externalIPs` to my pods service.yaml (api and nginx)

```
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8443"
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 80
  externalIPs:
      - 10.10.10.130
```